# XSL transformation failing in Oracle 11g

Tags: xml, oracle, xslt, oracle11g, oracle10g

I use XSLT transformation for creating html content from XML data. The transformation works perfectly in Oracle 10g. But, it fails to produce the html content in Oracle 11g. Gives the follow error

LPX-00660: Not a well-formed document or external entity.

Here is a sample code

```
declare
output clob;
   begin
       select XMLTRANSFORM(XMLType('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' ||
   '<DATA>' ||
   '    <ROWSET>' ||
   '        <ROW>' ||
   '            <TIME_CURRENT>04-DEC-2015 06:42 AM</TIME_CURRENT>' ||            
   '        </ROW>' ||
   '    </ROWSET>' ||
   '</DATA>'), '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' ||
   '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"' ||
   '    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">' ||
   '   <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"' ||
   '        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"' ||
   '        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" />' ||
   '    <xsl:template match="DATA">' ||
   '        <p>' ||
   '            Time Now:' ||
   '            <xsl:value-of select="ROWSET/ROW/TIME_CURRENT" />' ||
   '        </p>' ||
   '            <xsl:call-template name="create_table"></xsl:call-template>'        ||
   '    </xsl:template>' ||
   '    <xsl:template name="create_table">' ||
   '            <br/>' ||
   '            Total row count = <xsl:value-of select="count(ROWSET/ROW)"        />' ||
   '    </xsl:template>' ||
   '</xsl:stylesheet>').getClobval() into output from dual;
   dbms_output.put_line(output);
   end;
```

I found that the transformation was failing at the `<br/>` tag.

```
   '    <xsl:template name="create_table">' ||
   '            <br/>' ||
   '            Total row count = <xsl:value-of select="count(ROWSET/ROW)"        />' ||
   '    </xsl:template>'
```

When I remove this, the transformation works fine. Since, the output is required as html, removing any such tags from the code is not a solution for me.

Oracle 10g version = 10.2.0.5.0

Oracle 11g version = 11.2.0.4.0

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create a complete HTML document as the output? Then add a template `<xsl:template match="/"><html><head></head><body><xsl:apply-templates/></body></html></xsl:template>`. Otherwise, if you want to create some HTML fragment, then, based on the error message, I would try to have your `<xsl:template match="DATA">` create a `div` wrapper element around the other content.

Comment: Creating a wrapper `div` fixed the problem. Thanks a lot @MartinHonnen! Could you please explain it a bit more as to why it worked when a wrapper div was used? Both Java and Oracle 10g can do the transformation without the wrapper div. Is this something specific to Oracle 11g? Thanks again!

Comment: I am afraid I neither use Oracle 10g nor Oracle 11g, I just went by the error message and tried to guess what `Not a well-formed document or external entity` could mean. While it is true that XSLT in general can create a fragment as its result, most XML APIs have an XML type or representation of a well-formed document where a single root element contains all other documents. So I simply guessed that your HTML fragment with several top level elements did not fit into the result type that Oracle uses for representing the transformation result.